# How to remove a node inside an iterator in python xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, iterator, elementtree, xml.etree

How to remove the current node, while iterating through all nodes from root by `getiterator()` function?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for node in root.getiterator():
     #if some condition:
        #remove(node)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't remove nodes without knowing the parent, but the `xml.etree` package doesn't give you any way to access a parent from a given node.

The only way around this is matching the parent node instead:

```
for node in root.iter():
    if some_condition_matches_parent:
        for child in list(node.iter()):
            if some_condition_matches_child:
                node.remove(child)
```

If you switch to the `lxml` library (which implements the same API, but with additional enhancements), you *can* retrieve the parent node from any given node:

```
node.getparent().remove(node)
```

Note, while the pure-Python implementation of `Element.getiterator()` returns a list object, in the C implementation of the ElementTree module (a separate import on Python 2, transparently imported on Python 3 if available) the `getiterator()` method returns a live generator which requires a copy to be made.

On top of that, the `Element.getiterator()` method has been deprecated in Python 3.2 and will be removed altogether in Python 3.9. I replaced its use with `node.iter()` in the outer loop, and `list(node.iter())` in the inner.

Comment: I had a small issue with removing a node after adding it to another etree root since adding it adds a reference to that node and does not make a new node. I ended up using copy.deepcopy to get a copy of the node before removing it so I could add it to another tree. Hope that helps someone. :)

Comment: @Spartacus Thanks a lot for adding that comment! It took me a moment to understand, but I get it now: If you take a node from Tree A, and append it to Tree B, and then attempt to remove it from Tree A, you get some kinda "deleting shared memory" issue, and the solution was to make a `copy.deepcopy` and appending the COPY to Tree B, that way you could delete it from Tree A safely. Summarized in case others are as confused as I was at first.