# How to remove duplicate nodes xml Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have a special case xml file structure is something like :

```
<Root>
    <parent1>
         <parent2>
             <element id="Something" >
         </parent2>
     </parent1>
     <parent1>
         <element id="Something">
     </parent1>
</Root>
```

My use case is to remove the duplicated element , I want to remove the elements with same Id .  I tried the following code  with no positive outcome (its not finding the duplicate node)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

path = 'old.xml'

tree = ET.parse(path)
root = tree.getroot()
prev = None

def elements_equal(e1, e2):
    if type(e1) != type(e2):
        return False
    if e1.tag != e1.tag: return False
    if e1.text != e2.text: return False
    if e1.tail != e2.tail: return False
    if e1.attrib != e2.attrib: return False
    if len(e1) != len(e2): return False
    return all([elements_equal(c1, c2) for c1, c2 in zip(e1, e2)])

for page in root:                     # iterate over pages
elems_to_remove = []
for elem in page:
   for insideelem in page:
       if elements_equal(elem, insideelem) and elem != insideelem:
           print("found duplicate: %s" % insideelem.text)   # equal function works well
           elems_to_remove.append(insideelem)
           continue

for elem_to_remove in elems_to_remove:
    page.remove(elem_to_remove)
# [...]
tree.write("out.xml")
```

Can someone help me in letting me know how can i solve it. I am very new to python with almost zero experience .

Comment: What else is the output you are getting ? Are you are your example gets parsed correctly ? Element node does not seem to be having any corresponding closing tags .

Comment: As mentioned ( its not finding duplicate) , ignore the closing tags as its a sample xml

Comment: What is the expected output ? Should the output XML not have any of the 'element' node at all? Can you please post the expected output for your sample ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all what you're doing is a hard problem in the library you're using, see this question: [How to remove a node inside an iterator in python xml.etree.ElemenTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419754/how-to-remove-a-node-inside-an-iterator-in-python-xml-etree-elementree)

The solution to this would be to use `lxml` which "implements the same API but with additional enhancements". Then you can do the following fix.

You seem to be only traversing the second level of nodes in your XML tree. You're getting `root`, then walking the children its children. This would get you `parent2` from the first page and the `element` from your second page. Furthermore you wouldn't be comparing across pages here:

**your comparison will only find second-level duplicates within the same page.**

Select the right set of elements using a proper traversal function such as `iter`:

```
# Use a `set` to keep track of "visited" elements with good lookup time.
visited = set()
# The iter method does a recursive traversal
for el in root.iter('element'):
    # Since the id is what defines a duplicate for you
    if 'id' in el.attr:
        current = el.get('id')
        # In visited already means it's a duplicate, remove it
        if current in visited:
            el.getparent().remove(el)
        # Otherwise mark this ID as "visited"
        else:
            visited.add(current)
```